# rails_admin navigation hide model does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navigation, rails-admin

I have one model that I want to hide from Navigation on the left of rails_admin but it does not work. (I still want to access it, just want to hide it from the panel, so exclude does not count)

I have tried all three kind of code below but it does not work:

```
config.model 'Document' do
 visible false
end
```

from here: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Navigation

As well as the code:

```
config.model 'Document' do
   hide_from_navigation
end
```

from here: http://www.verious.com/code/foca/rails_admin/

As well as the code:

```
config.model 'Document' do
   navigation do
      visible = false
     end
end
```

Can someone explain for me why ?

I have already restart the server before checking it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I solved it adding the following line of code in config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:

```
config.excluded_models= [Document]
```

Instead of:

```
config.excluded_models = ['Document']
```

Answer (score 2):

in your app/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb file you can add something like this and only include the models you want to show up in your navigation --

```
config.included_models = [ User, Region, Newsletter, Article ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tested the first example :

```
config.model 'Document' do
 visible false
end
```

and it worked, the model was hidden.

Be sure to remember that you have to restart rails.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and unfortunately I haven't found any proper solution. The only workaround was to hack Rails Admin using javascript.

So, to hide the model Document from the navigation menu I added this code in 'app/assets/javascripts/rails_admin/custom/ui.js':

```
$(document).on('rails_admin.dom_ready', function() {
  $('ul.nav-pills li[data-model="document"]').hide();
});
```

I hope that a better way to do this is implemented soon.

Answer (score 0):

in your model:

```
rails_admin do
  visible false
end
```

no need to edit your rails_admin.rb file.